# The breakpoint will not currently be hit - Remote Debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, remote-debugging

I am having a problem with debugging a DLL (C#).
The DLL is running on a server and I'd like to debug it with the Remote Debugger Tool from Visual Studio 2010.

I actually can attach to the process, but somehow I always get the following problem at my breakpoint:
"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Edit: The .pdb is on the server too.

Comment: You will need to have the corresponding `.pdb` file for the DLL you are trying to debug.

Comment: Sorry, i did not mention that. The ".pdb" is on the server too.

Comment: Then it could be that either VS is not finding it (I think you can specify the actual location of the `.pdb` file through some setting) or else, sometimes you need to compile the DLL yourself and use those `.pdb` files.

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's hard to tell, but are you sure the code is reachable (i.e. not in a branch that will never be executed, because it evaluates to `if (false)`)?

Comment: The code is 100% reachable. I also tried it with some Testlogs. -> I come there!

Comment: Server == Release build? Can VS find the release build PDB? Personally I don't think it would look on the server to find it. Configure your symbol path locally.

Comment: How can I edit my symbol path?

Answer (score 13):

How are you getting the .pdb and .dll files on the remote server? They need to match exactly what is on your local machine. Look at the size of the files and make sure they match between the remote server and your local machine. If they are being built on different machines or with different build configs they will not match. You can copy/paste the bin folder from your local machine to the remote server to make sure the files match exactly. (Back up the server's bin first)

Are you attached to the right process? If you're not sure, try attaching to a few different processes. If your breakpoints work, one of those new processes is the correct one.

Try adding the remote server's bin folder as a symbol file location. This can be done in Options > Tools > Debugging > Symbols. This will tell Visual Studio to check that folder for symbol files.

I wrote [this blog post](http://blog.brendanlacanette.com/2016/09/remote-debugging-breakpoint-will-not.html) about this after I faced the same issue, it may have a bit more information that will help.

Comment: Thank you for this, adding the server's bin folder was the key - no one else seems to have mentioned that!

Comment: I've replaced `bin` folders on a remote server by folders from my PC. Otherwise the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019) mentions that we have to publish sources exactly from a PC where we run Visual Studio for remote debugging.

Comment: Possibly, it is OK to have symbols (.dll, .pdb) compiled on different machines with different paths in `.pdb` files. But they must have the same configuration. I.e. Debug or Release, etc.